# serving flask via nginx and gunicorn in docker

Tags: python, nginx, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

Playing around with flask I would like to get a real setup up and running in docker. This means flask should be served via nginx and gunicorn. I set up a sample code repository https://github.com/geoHeil/pythonServing but so far can't get nginx to work properly.

Flask is served on `application:5000`, docker should resolve application to its respective name.

Nginx config is as follows:

```
server {

    listen 8080;
    server_name application;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://application:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

which looks good to me. So far I cant find the problem.

## edit

compose file is here. Command to start was

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up

version: '2'
services:
  application:
    restart: always
    build: ./application
    command: gunicorn -w 4 --bind :5000 wsgi:application
    links:
      - db
    expose:
     - "5000"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    links:
      - application
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - "8880:8080"
```

Comment: try to ping application from nginx container.

Comment: @FarhadFarahi indeed, that works just fine as `PING application (192.168.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.129 ms`

Comment: Gimmie the commands you ran to setup the environment, if you use docker compose please provide compose file.

Comment: @FarhadFarahi please see the edit as well as https://github.com/geoHeil/pythonServing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **nginx** config file is in a wrong location.

Steps to fix:

```
sudo docker-compose down
```

Delete nginx image:

```
sudo docker images
sudo docker rmi 
REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
pythonserving_nginx              latest              152698f13c7a        About a minute ago   54.3 MB

sudo docker rmi pythonserving_nginx
```

Now change the nginx **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM nginx:1.11.8-alpine
MAINTAINER geoheil

ADD sites-enabled.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled.conf
```

Please note the location of nginx config.

Now try this docker-compose file (Using User-defined Networks):

```
version: '2'
services:
  application:
    restart: always
    build: ./application
    command: gunicorn -w 4 --bind :5000 wsgi:application
    networks:
      - testnetwork
    expose:
     - "5000"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:9.6.1-alpine
    networks:
      - testnetwork
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=d
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=d
      - POSTGRES_DB=d
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    networks:
      - testnetwork
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - "8880:8080"
networks:
  testnetwork:
```

And Bring up containers:

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Browse to http://localhost:8880

Comment: strange. that does not yet work. Nothing in the access or error logs.

Comment: Did u do all the steps? Because I tried it. Specially removing old images to make compose build new ones

Comment: Indeed, I deleted the image. It does not work for me. I am using docker for mac though.

Comment: I retried on a fresh VM ubuntu. Same problem there.

Comment: `sudo docker exec -it <nginx container ID> /bin/sh` then `ls /etc/nginx/` and ls `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`, gimme the output for both `ls` commands

Comment: here is the output https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/106a88100b40384cfdeaacee92df64de as well as cat of configuration files

Comment: Your config file location is correct. check out my edit (docker compose file)

Comment: Shouldn't the default network work as well when the containers are linked?

Comment: It should, As you can see, I removed links, Just try it out. linking is a legacy feature anyway.

Comment: Strange. This does not resolve the problem for me. Same problem persists. Still I can access the application container from nginx, but nothing is present on 8080

Comment: you should access the nginx on port 8880 not 8080, open up a browser and `http://localhost:8880`

Comment: Now it works. would you go with --link or the network option?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133750/discussion-between-farhad-farahi-and-georg-heiler).

Answer (score -1):

```
Smaple docker file

FROM python:3.5

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libatlas-base-dev gfortran nginx supervisor

RUN pip3 install uwsgi

COPY ./requirements.txt /project/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r /project/requirements.txt

RUN useradd --no-create-home nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN rm -r /root/.cache

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY flask-site-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi/
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/

COPY /app /project

WORKDIR /project

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```