# Nginx not serving my Flask website

Tags: python, nginx, web, docker-compose

I am following this [example](http://feisky.xyz/2015/02/11/how-to-use-docker-compose-to-deploy-a-flask-app/) and this [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789585/serving-flask-via-nginx-and-gunicorn-in-docker) and I am stuck.
I am running this example on a digitalocean VPS. My file structure is as follows:

### project structure

```
      docker-compose.yml
      mainweb/
      nginx/
      README
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    app:
        restart: always
        build: ./mainweb
        command: gunicorn -w 2 -b :5000 wsgi:app
        networks:
            - mainnet
        expose:
            - "5000"
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    nginx:
        restart: always
        build: ./nginx
        networks:
            - mainnet
        links:
            - app
        volumes:
            - /www/static
        expose:
            - 8080
        ports:
            - "8880:8080"
networks:
    mainnet:
```

## mainweb/

```
  app.py
  Dockerfile
  requirements.txt
  templates/
  wsgi.py
```

### mainweb/app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home()():
    return render_template('templates/home.html')


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

### mainweb/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.5
MAINTAINER castellanprime

RUN mkdir /mainweb
COPY . /mainweb
WORKDIR /mainweb
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

## mainweb/templates/

```
   home.html
```

### mainweb/templates/home.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> My website </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> I am here </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

### mainweb/wsgi.py

```
from app import app

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

## nginx

```
   Dockerfile
   sites-enabled.conf
   static/
```

### nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.13.1-alpine
MAINTAINER castellanprime
ADD sites-enabled.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled.conf
ADD static/ /www/static/
```

### nginx/sites-enabled.conf

```
server{

    listen 8080;
    server_name app;  #  Should I put my actual www.XXXXXX.XXXXX address here
    charset utf-8;

    location /static{
        alias /www/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X_Forwared-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

## nginx/static

```
   css/
   js/
```

After I run the command `docker-compose up -d`, I check the www.XXXXXX.com:8880, or www.XXXXXX.com:8080 from another web client on another system.
I get the standard nginx web page.

How do I redirect it to the home.html?

Comment: You should really follow some of the FAQs about posting questions, elsewise, you'll be shut down!

Comment: @RobertMoskal I posted the full file structure as I am not familiar with nginx. What was wrong with my posting and how can I reduce the scope of the question? The FAQ states an SSCE, I tried to not totally deviate from the answers already given from the links.

Comment: Remove Nginx and Gunicorn, then tell us if flask  doesn't work. You  have too many components to debug

Comment: Also, the help center says post a [mcve] **in the question itself**, which means no gists. All that text can be in the question

Comment: Another question: Are you running docker locally, or remotely? Maybe there's a firewall you're not opening

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for showing me that I can not have gists. I will not make that mistake again. I will repost all the text in the question. Also, I indicated that I am following a previous stackoverflow question and wanted to do a similar thing. So just using Flask by itself would not be exactly what I want.

Comment: My point is two fold 1) You don't need Gunicorn unless the Flask app is running on the same machine as Nginx 2) You should be able to access port 5000 (or whatever Flask is on) without Nginx

Comment: @cricket_007 The Flask app is running on the same machine as the nginx and in hopefully in different docker containers. Is the Docker not neccessary or too complex to solve.

Comment: Docker isn't the problem I'm talking about. Gunicorn is meant to the uWSGI container that Nginx mounts to on the same host (or in the same container). http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/uwsgi/.

Comment: @cricket_007 Could we continue this discussion in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147500/discussion-between-corax-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a step back and run the Flask app alone.

You have some syntax errors.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():   # Remove double brackets
    return render_template('home.html')  # The templates folder is already picked up

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Then in a Docker container, and without gunicorn

```
FROM python:3.5

RUN mkdir /mainweb
COPY . /mainweb
WORKDIR /mainweb
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python3","/mainweb/app.py"]
```

And run it, and see if it works.

```
cd mainapp
docker build -t flask:test .
docker run --rm -p 5000:5000 flask:test
```

Open http://server:5000

Then start on docker-compose with just that container and define nginx if you want.

nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.13.1-alpine
ADD flask.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 8080
```

nginx/flask.conf (I changed this based on a file that I have in a project)

```
server {

    listen 8080;    # This is the port to EXPOSE in nginx container
    server_name app;  # You can change this, but not necessary
    charset utf-8;

    location ^~ /static/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/; 
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @flask;
    }

    location @flask {
        proxy_pass http://app:5000;   # This is the port Flask container EXPOSE'd
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X_Forwared-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

And finally, the compose. You don't want to have your site exposing both 5000 and 80 (you don't want people to bypass nginx), so just don't expose 5000

```
version: '2'
services:
    app:
        restart: always
        build: ./mainweb
        networks:
            - mainnet
    nginx:
        restart: always
        build: ./nginx
        networks:
            - mainnet
        links:
            - app
        volumes:
            - ./mainweb/static:/usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
            - "80:8080"
networks:
    mainnet:
```