# Docker container not running even when I did docker start container ID

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to dockerise a python application I built.

Basically, I ran docker and was able to build successfully the first time round. I made a slight change to the python application and I re-ran the build and run command.

```
vagrant@ansible:~/Desktop/braintree_example_docker$ sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 python-braintree-app
906760d4eb5484c4feb7d47c3cf394aa20604eefa22b82157c870440b14c6f4d
```

However, when I did a docker PS: nothing was shown.

I then did a docker ps-a and it showed the below

```
vagrant@ansible:~/Desktop/braintree_example_docker$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
906760d4eb54        python-braintree-app   "python app.py"          5 minutes ago       Exited (0) 3 minutes ago                           goofy_pike
016ceba53f9d        python-braintree-app   "python app.py"          9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 8 minutes ago                           pedantic_chebyshev
9e23e8412f63        python-braintree-app   "python app.py"          10 minutes ago      Exited (0) 10 minutes ago                          nosta
```

I tried to do a `docker start 906760d4eb5484c4feb7d47c3cf394aa20604eefa22b82157c870440b14c6f4d` but still shows docker ps as nothing.

What am i doing wrong?

PS: a newbie to docker sp please excuse the silly question

A second question, is if I made a code change into my Python application, do I need to rebuild my image?

Comment: Please remove `-d` flag, and look at the errors that are killing your container

Comment: And yes, if there are code changes, you must re-build the container, or more specifically, the layer that runs your application code

Comment: Do u mean sudo docker run -p 5000:5000 python-braintree-app?

Comment: Yes, what output does that generate? Also, please edit the question to include a [mcve] of the flask app and dockerfile

Comment: FWIW, see my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44732284/2308683

Comment: Ah i know why. I had a syntax issue Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question as rightly pointed out by cricket_007, I had to add in a host and port in my code.

this was the cause of my issue